# Button with different spacing on Android and Iphone

Tags: css, iphone, google-chrome, woocommerce, safari

The codes for these buttons (pink color) are rendering perfectly in all CSS @medias on these devices:

- Chrome/Firefox/Opera with Windows/Linux/Android
- Safari with Iphone 8
- Device Simulators: Blisk Browser, ResponsivelyApp-1.3.0, lambdatest.com

But it shows the image error in:

- Chrome/Safari with Iphone 13 and 14 pro max (428x926px and 430x932px)

[image]

Are there any errors in the CSS? Or could it be improved for greater compatibility?

Link to inspect:

https://floristeria-08.angratres.com.br/

Codes:

```css
@media (min-width:300px) {

.woocommerce a.button, .woocommerce button.button, .woocommerce .woocommerce-message a.button, .woocommerce #respond input#submit.alt, .woocommerce a.button.alt, .woocommerce button.button.alt, .woocommerce input.button.alt, .woocommerce input.button, .woocommerce-cart table.cart td.actions .button, .woocommerce form.checkout_coupon .button, .woocommerce #respond input#submit, .wc-block-grid__products .wc-block-grid__product .wp-block-button__link, .woocommerce ul.products li.product.mobile-align-left .star-rating, .woocommerce ul.products li.product.mobile-align-left .button, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.mobile-align-left .star-rating, .woocommerce-page ul.products li.product.mobile-align-left .button {

        padding-right: 24%;
        padding-left: 24%;
        border: 1px solid;

    }
}
```

```html
 <div class="wp-block-button wc-block-grid__product-add-to-cart">
    
    <a href="?add-to-cart=820" aria-label="Adicionar “Maternidade Menina” no seu carrinho" data-quantity="1" data-product_id="820" data-product_sku="" rel="nofollow" class="wp-block-button__link  add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart">Comprar</a>

</div>
```